# calling a function with setinterval within another function in google maps apv v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, setinterval

i am writing this code to call a function after some time interval but the function is not preforming it functionality .when i am normally calling the function pus() it is running but with setInterval it is not working.please give me its solution.

```
 var ltnlg = null;
 var flightPlanCoordinates = [];
 var nl2 = 10.9646;
 var ng2 = 72.8787;
 var lt2, ln2;
 var ltnlg = null;

 function lin() {
           flightPlanCoordinates = [
     new google.maps.LatLng(29.0167, 77.3833),
     new google.maps.LatLng(21.7679, 78.8718),
     new google.maps.LatLng(18.9647, 72.8258)
     ];

          var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
               path: flightPlanCoordinates,
               strokeColor: "#FF0000",
               strokeOpacity: 1.0,
               strokeWeight: 2
               });

           flightPath.setMap(map);
           pl = new google.maps.Polyline();
           //  window.setInterval("pus()", 10000);
          pus();

           }
       }

       function pus() {



           ltnlg = new google.maps.LatLng(nl2, ng2);
           flightPlanCoordinates.push(ltnlg);
           lt2 = nl2;
            n12 = lt2 + 0.0660;
          ln2 = ng2;
          ng2 = ln2 + 0.0660;

       }
```

Answer (score 2):

Never pass callback as string.

```
window.setInterval(pus, 10000);
```

or if you want pass some params

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    pus(a, b, c);
}, 10000);
```

Comment: window.setInterval(pus,10000);

Answer (score 1):

The question here should not be "*why this didn't work with setInterval*", it should be "*why does it work from within the function*" , because it shouldn't.

I guess the drawing of the polygon is a asynchronous process, it's not finished when you call `pus()` from within the function, that's why the changes made on `flightPlanCoordinates` will still have an effect.

But the correct way to apply the modified path to the polyline is to call in `pus()` :

```
flightPath.setPath(flightPlanCoordinates);
```

(Note: you must make `flightPath` global to be able to access it from outside of `lin()`)